# why this function is not returning value expected

Tags: c++, function, recursion, return

below is a `searchVal` function for searching a value in a binary tree. nodes of binary tree are stored in a vector `nodeVec` with first object in vector as root.

**structure of nodes**

```
class bst{
public:
    //other functions..//
    int searchVal(int)
private:
    bst *lLink;
    int info;
    bst *rLink;
```

}

**calling part in main**

```
cout << "Enter Value to search ";
int val;
cin >> val;
int ret = nodeVec[0].searchVal(val);

if (ret == 2)
    cout << "Value Not Found" << endl << endl;
else
    cout << "Value Found" << endl << endl;
```

**Function**

```
int bst::searchVal(int val)
{
    if (info != val)
    {
        if (info > val)
        {
            if (lLink != NULL)
                lLink->searchVal(val);
            else
                return 2;
        }
        if (info < val)
        {
            if (rLink != NULL)
                rLink->searchVal(val);
           else
                return 2;
        }
    }

    if (info == val)
        return 1;
}
```

while debugging (using codeBlocks) i observed that after any condition is met for example if the condition `info==val` is met the execution pointer (arrow in the IDE pointing to line being processed) goes to end of `searchVal` and after that it go to nearest `if`(from the end) however it does not go into the block of that condition. It always returns the `info` stored in root node in `ret` not `1` or `2`

Comment: How do you initialise `info`?

Comment: @VusP that's another part of the the whole code which uses vector to take values from user and from that vector create a global vector `nodeVec` of objects and link the nodes (using the rLink, lLink  part)as per the criteria required to create a binary search tree. But that's not a problem every part is working fine even the traversal for searching the value works well only problem is that the `searchVal` not returning the expected value i.e, `1` or '2'

Comment: you have already got the solutionby Peter. I just thought maybe its got to do something with improper initialisation of `info`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the major problem in your code is that you're not returning the result of the sub-tree searches; i.e. you should be doing this:

```
if(lLink!=NULL)
    return lLink->searchVal(val);
```

You're missing the `return` keyword. That means that some execution paths go all the way through to the end of the function, and never hit a `return`, which is potentially very bad. The compiler should be issuing an error or warning about that though.

Answer (score 4):

Should be

```
  if(lLink!=NULL)
  return lLink->searchVal(val);
  ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

The `searchVal` function needs a return value on every code path - everything else has undefined behaviour (which means that anything could happen).

Add a `return` to your calls to `lLink->searchVal` and `rLink->searchVal`.

(And if your compiler didn't warn you about this, you need to enable that warning.)